# DispForm with child data view

Tags: 2010, list-view, data-view-web-part, datasheet

I have two related lists.  I have a parent list and a child list, the child list has a column that stores the ID of the parent list.  In the parent's EditForm I added a dataview of the child list, and filtered it by the parent's ID.  This is working okay, but I would like to display the child list in a Datasheet view so that editing and inserting is faster.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet view is difficult to work with in that regard.  You'll probably need to make your child list a multiple item form.  This will allow for each line item in the child list to be edited on the fly, not as conveniently as a datasheet view but faster than editing each item individually through the UI.

Comment: When you say "multiple item form" do you mean "inline editing" or something else?

Comment: When you insert a DVWP into a page in SharePoint Designer, you have various options, single item display form, single item edit form, etc.  One of them is Multiple Item Edit form and it does allow for inline editing within the DVWP.

Comment: I got this working, but not 100% happy with it.  It wasn't quite as "fast" as the datasheet.  But with the datasheet it seems impossible to set filtering and/or pre-fill columns.  Thanks for the good suggestion though!

Comment: Glad it was useful.  The datasheet view is inflexible in that regard, it would be much easier if it weren't locked down.  The alternative would be to roll your own display with something like jquery/jqueryui and get something ajaxy to post back the data.